# The Uno Platform button cannot be clicked

Tags: uwp, platform, uno

I'm still trying on the Uno Platform, but there's a reaction

I wrote the following code in MainPage.xaml:
`<Grid> <Button Content="点击" Click="buttonIngerprintRecognition"></Button> <TextBlock Name="textBlock" Text="not clicked"></TextBlock> </Grid>`
I wrote the following code in MainPage.xaml.cs:
`public void buttonIngerprintRecognition(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { textBlock.Text = "clicked"; }`
I run a windows program. Now I put a breakpoint on the first line of the method and click the button, but the program fails to stop at the first line of the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the button click event cannot respond is that the textblock blocks the button. It is recommended to use StackPanel or [RelativePanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.relativepanel?view=winrt-22621) to avoid the controls from overlapping.

Comment: I'm sorry to reply to you now, and thank you very much for recovering this problem. My program has this error is that I don't understand some of the basic operations of the UI. After reading an article, I learned that Grid will overlap. However, I should have noticed it very early, because I encountered similar problems when I wrote the login page before.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem, but I'm still ignorant, so I need to add this trivial generation.

```xml
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="点击" Click="buttonIngerprintRecognition"></Button>
        <TextBlock Name="textBlock" Text="未点击"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```